Prevent Laravel 11 from setting any cookies (including session/xsrf-cookies)?
Is it possible to prevent Laravel from setting any form of cookies until a user has allowed it? I have found some cookie-consent-packages on github, but none of them prevent Laravel from setting an initial session-cookie or xsrf-cookie.
Can I intercept the sessions/xsrf-cookies with some kind of middleware/configuration and block/allow it depending if a consent-cookie is found or not?

I couldn't get the author's answer to work because StartSession does not seem to part of the regular middleware stack and is instead tied to the SessionServiceProvider which invokes it directly.
Instead of trying to mess with Laravel internals, I was able to write a middleware which does most of what I want: if a consent cookie is present or a session cookie is already in the request, everything works as normal. Otherwise it prevents the session from being persisted to storage (db or otherwise) and strips the session and XSRF cookies from the response.
Note that this means the cookie needs to be set before a valid CSRF token is available and any tokens inserted in forms prior will be invalid. Laravel's CSRF logic is strongly tied to the session logic so sadly I don't see any way to avoid this issue (even allowing the XSRF cookie would not work as the value is normally compared to one stored in the session).
This means that forms that need to work without setting the consent cookie (e.g. a consent dialog) can not use Laravel's CSRF protection. I think this is an acceptable risk for my purposes but YMMV.
Here is the middleware itself:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Concerns\ExcludesPaths;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ConsensualCookies
{
    use ExcludesPaths;

    protected static $except = [];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $sessionCookie = Config::get('session.cookie');
        if (
            $request->cookies->has('consent') ||
            $request->cookies->has($sessionCookie) ||
            $this->inExceptArray($request)
        ) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        // Prevent the session from being persisted to storage
        Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
        $response = $next($request);
        // Strip the XSRF and session cookies
        $response->headers->removeCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
        $response->headers->removeCookie($sessionCookie);
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Get the URIs that should be excluded.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getExcludedPaths()
    {
        return $this::$except ?? [];
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the given URIs should be excluded.
     *
     * @param  array|string  $uris
     * @return void
     */
    public static function except(string|array $path): void
    {
        if (is_array($path)) {
            static::$except = array_merge(static::$except, $path);
            return;
        }
        static::$except[] = $path;
    }
}

I've created an invokable ConsentController that sets the consent cookie. Adding its URL to ConsensualCookies::except allows the session and CSRF middlewares to add their cookies for those requests but because of the absence of an incoming CSRF token this must also be added to VerifyCsrfToken::except.
Here is the minimal bootstrap/app.php required to make this work:
<?php
 
use App\Http\Middleware\ConsensualCookies;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;
 
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        // Exempt the /consent controller route from both middlewares
        ConsensualCookies::except('/consent');
        VerifyCsrfToken::except('/consent');
        // Add the middleware before all other middlewares
        $middleware->prependToGroup("web", ConsensualCookies::class);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

Here's my controller. Again, YMMV:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class ConsentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        // We only need this if we don't have a session cookie,
        // so the TTL could also be shorter depending on your use case.
        Cookie::queue('consent', 'ok', 60 * 24 * 30);
        return response(status: 204);
    }
}

Remember to add it to your routes/web.php:
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ConsentController;

Route::post('/consent', ConsentController::class);

It's probably worth noting that none of this is strictly necessary for compliance with the EU GDPR and e-Privacy laws, although I am not a lawyer. Plenty of sites set these kinds of cookies using the "technically required" justification the GDPR allows using instead of obtaining consent. I'm not aware of any rulings on whether this also holds when setting the cookies before the user is informed about them but I think it's unlikely to cause issues.
This approach does feel cleaner to me, personally, and has the benefit of avoiding cluttering up the session storage for every one-time visitor, though. If Laravel's CSRF logic did not rely on sessions, we might be able to get Laravel to provide a "lazy sessions" option that would only persist the session (and set the cookie) if the session holds any data. At this time, however, that would always be the case due to the way the CSRF logic works. I think my answer provides a good enough workaround for those who want to postpone session creation (at the cost of also postponing CSRF protection) until the user has been informed about the use of these cookies.

I have solved it, but not sure if it's the correct way. This is how I did it:

Create a new middleware named CustomStartSession, extending StartSession and overriding the handleStatefulRequest()-method:

class CustomStartSession extends StartSession
{
    protected function handleStatefulRequest(Request $request, $session, Closure $next)
    {
        // check if consent-cookie is set
        $consent = $request->cookies->has('consent');

        $request->setLaravelSession(
            $this->startSession($request, $session)
        );

        $this->collectGarbage($session);
        $response = $next($request);
        $this->storeCurrentUrl($request, $session);

        // if consent-cookie is set, add the cookie
        if ($consent) {
            $this->addCookieToResponse($response, $session);
        }

        $this->saveSession($request);

        return $response;
    }
}


Then in bootstrap/app.php, replacing StartSession with CustomStartSession, and removing ValidateCsrfToken:

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        // replace StartSession with CustomStartSession
        $middleware->web(replace: [StartSession::class => CustomStartSession::class]);

        // remove ValidateCsrfToken-middleware
        $middleware->web(remove: [ValidateCsrfToken::class]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

Should probably subclassing ValidateCsrfToken too and check for the consent-cookie there too. Right now I decided to remove it completely as I don't have any "important" forms in my project.

I have to say the Laravel 11 way of configuring the middleware classes is a huge pain compared to pre 11.

I can't seem to get this solution to work. Replacing the middleware at this point does nothing - in fact, even removing it has no effect. Removing (or replacing) it in routes/web.php with withoutMiddleware however crashes the request. It looks like this middleware is injected directly by the session provider.
